# MySQL and Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I have a question regarding Foreign Keys in an InnoDB Table. I have 4 tables in my database:

**Signup:**

- UID - Primary Key
- Afid
- Planid
- Industryid

**Affiliates:**

- Afid - Primary Key

**Plans:**

- Planid - Primary Key

**Industries:**

- Industryid - Primary Key

SQL I use to add the keys:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_industries` FOREIGN KEY (`industryid`) REFERENCES `industries` (`industryid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_affiliates` FOREIGN KEY (`afid`) REFERENCES `affiliates` (`afid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_plans` FOREIGN KEY (`planid`) REFERENCES `plans` (`planid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**What my question is:**

If I was to delete a plan or an industry on their respective tables would the user in the signup table be deleted? I have tried to find guides on this and they don't explain it very well.

Basically what I need done is that the row in the signup table never to be deleted no matter what. When I use this query:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_plans` FOREIGN KEY (`planid`) REFERENCES `plans` (`planid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot delete a parent row.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the row in Signup to stay even if you delete the referenced row in Industries, Affiliates, or Plans, then you have two choices:

- Do not declare a foreign key constraint.  This removes enforcement of referential integrity, but it allows rows to exist in Signup that reference a parent primary key value that no longer exists.
- Use ON DELETE SET NULL.  This allows the row to stay, but the foreign key value that references the now-deleted parent will be changed.*

For more details see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

* The standard SQL specification also defines a rule ON DELETE SET DEFAULT, but InnoDB doesn't support this feature.

Comment: So there is no way to change the value on delete to something I pick (ex. 5 or 6)?

Comment: You could write a trigger to do that.  Or change it from application code with an UPDATE before you DELETE the parent it references.